# How to identify touched Cell in LazyVerticalGrid jetPack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

i have code below in xml android i want to change it to jetpack Compose

```
gridview.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
        int action = motionEvent.getActionMasked();
        float currentXPosition = motionEvent.getX();
        float currentYPosition = motionEvent.getY();
        int position = gridview.pointToPosition((int) currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return parase_Down(position);
        }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            return parase_Move(position);
        }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            return parase_Up();
        }
        return true;
    });
```

How to identify touched Cell postions from Coordinates x and y ( pointToPosition )

Comment: You can simply use a clickable modifier inside each item

Comment: @GabrieleMariottiGA no this is will not work i want to get Position of Cell every time Grid is touched and added touched Cell too List

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to each item the [`detectTapGestures`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputScope).detectTapGestures(kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction2,kotlin.Function1)). It will return the `offset` representing the position relative to the containing element.

Something like:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(3)
) {
    itemsIndexed(itemsIndexedList) { index, item ->

        Text("Item at index $index is $item",
            modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures { offset ->
                    Log.i("Grid", "Clicked item=$index offset=$offset")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: this work if you tap on Cell i want to detects Cell Position when touched cell and move in grid  -- ACTION_MOVE